# mysql: turn on the general log

Tags: mysql, xampp, logfile

I try to turn on the general log on the mysql
I use the xampp as the local server and this is my.ini

```
log_output = FILE
general_log = 1
general_log = "mysql_query.log"
```

I can't find the file at all, please help

Comment: By Default  Xampp Stores mysql Log in `C:\xampp\mysql\data` If you have installed Xampp in `C:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I type it wrong XD

it should be...

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = "mysql_query.log"
```

and don't forget to check log_output variable to be "FILE"

Answer (score 5):

where is log located?

```
mysql> SHOW variables like '%general_log%';

+------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value              |
+------------------+--------------------+
| general_log      | ON                 |
| general_log_file | /tmp/your_path.log |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

you want change location?

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'file name';
```

Answer (score 1):

just found the answer, probably will help someone

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html
as root

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```